# How to extract a number of days worked in the first month of employment from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I use MySQL. I have a database with data about employees: name, lastname, hiredate (year-month-day). I want to get a number of days worked in the first month of employment. The months have different number of days and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I think TIMESTAMPDIFF() function could be useful, but I can't figure out the proper syntax.
I am a beginner in SQL and would apprecate your forbearance.

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055) and update your question with DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;`), sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column called `hiredate` of type `DATE`, you can determine the last day of the month where the person was hired with [LAST_DAY(hiredate)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(hiredate) AS hired_in_month_ending
```

Then you can determine the number of *calendar days* between the hire date and the end of the month with [DATEDIFF(end, start)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

```sql
SELECT 1 + DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY(hiredate), hiredate) AS calendar_days_in_month_hired
```

(The `1 +`  is to deal with the fact that a person hired on the last day of the month actually was on payroll for one day.)

As far as the number of *days worked*, that depends on all sorts of factors you didn't mention. Weekends? Holidays? Absences?

Comment: This is a toy database for an assignment, so weekends, holidays and absences are not mentioned in a database. Thank you for such a clear answer.

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF() also works well, but you have to add 1 too